# Delphi - setting object fields to Empty

Tags: delphi, rtti

I can't seem to set the object fields to empty despite making an explicit call to SomeRttiField.SetValue. Here's the pseudo code:

```
var
  A: TRTTIField;
..
begin
  A.SetValue(A_Instance, TValue.Empty);

  if A.GetValue(A_Instance).IsEmpty then
    ShowMessage('Empty.'); //---- this never happens
end;
```

Comment: It's probably better if you post **real code** instead of **pseudo code** if you want help here.

Comment: Agreed. I simply cannot understand why you would choose not to show a complete program. You could do it in about 10-15 lines of code. Why would you not do so and give us more work and make it less likely to get an answer.

Comment: Aside from the psuedocode, it is still a valid question, isn't it?

Comment: @whosrdaddy No it's not because we've no idea what types are involved.